# Setting path in Python

Tags: python, path

Is there a way to set the terminal path in Python? I have some compiled binaries that I'll like to use in a folder, let's just say `foo.exe` in  `C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.2/bin`, and I figured there had to be something in the `os` or `sys` modules that would work, but I couldn't find any:

```
# This works, but ugly
psqldir = 'C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.2/bin'
currentdir = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(psqldir)
os.system('foo')
os.chdir(currentdir)

# Does not work
os.system('set PATH=%PATH%;C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.2/bin')
os.system('foo')

# Does not work
sys.path.append('C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.2\\bin')
os.system('foo')
```

Thanks!

Comment: `os.system()`? Not good...

Comment: Ouch. Is there a better style? I'm open to suggestion.

Comment: @ephedyn See the last sentence of kindall's answer.

Comment: @Aya I don't see any answer from a kindall, did something happen? Btw your answer does exactly what I was trying to do - thanks!

Comment: Alas, kindall has deleted their answer - whyever. So the answer is "Use the `subprocess` module".

Comment: @glglgl Awesome, got it.

Comment: I forgot to link to [`subprocess`'s documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work...

```
import os

psqldir = 'C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.2/bin'
os.environ['PATH'] = '%s;%s' % (os.environ['PATH'], psqldir)
os.system('foo')
```

...or just call `foo.exe` by its full path...

```
os.system('C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.2/bin/foo')
```

However, as kindall's (now-deleted) answer suggested, it's worth noting this paragraph from the [`os.system()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) documentation...

> The [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new 
>   processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using
>   this function. See the [Replacing Older Functions with the subprocess Module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements)
>   section in the `subprocess` documentation for some helpful recipes.

Comment: +1 for calling with full path, -0.4 for not recommending `subprocess`, makes +0.6, rounds to +1.

Comment: @glglgl I thought it'd be rude to usurp kindall's suggestion of `subprocess`, but now he's deleted it, I'll add it in.

Answer (score 1):

How I understand this is that you need to add an environment variable . I think you should be able to do that using os.system / os.environ or subprocess . 
Also considering that you are on windows you might want to check these articles

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/416087/

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/159462/

Comment: Thanks for the tips, will go through them.